# JBoss starting with only EJB Container

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x

I am currently writing a web application which uses JBoss6.x as the application server, for load sharing what I have decided is to write some EJB's which can be either run locally on the same machine as the web application on the Jboss or in a separate machine which will be remotely connected which will have Jboss running on it.

Now the question here is, I would be needing only 1 JBoss server to serve the web application, all other Jboss in question should be running with only the EJB Containers. Is it possible to run only the EJB Container and the naming services so that I can remotely connect to the same? Pointers or specific links as to how to go about doing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can refer these links https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss5xTuningSlimming
 & https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss6xTuningSlimming

Comment: @NayanWadekar I am looking at using Jboss As 7

Comment: You have tagged your post with jboss6.x, therefore commented accordingly. Then update post with relevant tag, will help others.

Comment: @NayanWadekar apologies, modified.